# How to add a key in a dictionary? (from existing data)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key

I am currently trying to create a dictionary with different keys. This is my code so far:

```
fh = open("plateau.txt", "r")
str=fh.read()
fh.close()

lines=str.split("\n")

d = dict()
currentKey = None
for line in lines:
    if ":" in line:
        currentKey    = line.strip(":")
        d[currentKey] = []
    else:
        d[currentKey].append(tuple(line.split(" ")))
print(d)
```

Once I do that, I receive a dictionary as such:

```
{'map': [('39', '41')], 'hubs': [('21', '3', '1500', '25'), ('21', '38', '1500', '25')], 'peaks': [('10', '10', '200'), ('11', '10', '300'), ('12', '10', '400'), ('10', '11', '200'), ('10', '12', '500'), ('',)]}
```

I'd like to keep **map**,**hubs** and **peaks** as keys but to add new ones so that 'x':*the first number in each*, 'y':*the 2nd number*, etc. How should I do that? I'm scared to mess up my code because I feel like I'm almost there! thanks for the help.

Comment: What if you have more than two values? The first two should be `x` and `y`, what about the third and the fourth?

Comment: @filbranden 3rd would be 'z' and 4th 'health' (in the case of my game)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `tuple(line.split(" "))` for this:

```
{ k:int(v) for k,v in zip(("x","y","z","health"),line.split(" ")) }
```

This will give you something that will probably be easier to manipulate than having separate keys with hard to match values between keys:

```
{ 
   'map': [{"x":39, "y":41}], 
  'hubs': [{"x":21, "y":3, "z":1500, "health":25}, {"x":21, "y":38, "z":1500, "health":25}], 
 'peaks': ...
}
```